# Creating a dynamic report without data source and putting data in detail band along with page footer and page header

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using *JasperReportBuilder* and exporting the report to *PDF*. The entire content of the report is generated by *MultiPageListBuilder*, *HorizontalListBuilder* and *VerticalListBuilder* and I don't want to pass the data source as data is coming from various data sources. I want to utilize page footer as well as page header for adding to static page header and footer on each page as well as page number. If I try to use *addDetail(componentBuilder)* method to add 
*MultiPageListBuilder* in *Detail& band (as this *MultiPageListBuilder* contains multiple page data), blank report generates. If I add *MultiPageListBuilder* in *Title* or *Summary* band, report generates perfectly but *Page Header* and *Page Footer* bands disappear.

A example code snippet is as follows

```
JasperReportBuilder rpt = net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.report();
MultiPageListBuilder multiPageList = cmp.multiPageList();
HorizontalListBuilder hrbld = cmp.horizontalList();

try {    
    rpt.addTitle(cmp.text("REPORT TITLE"));
    rpt.addTitle(cmp.text("--------------"));

    rpt.addPageHeader(cmp.pageXofY());

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        hrbld = cmp.horizontalList();
        hrbld.add(cmp.text("ABC " + i)).newRow();
        multiPageList.add(hrbld);
    }

    rpt.addDetail(multiPageList);

    rpt.summaryOnANewPage();
    rpt.addSummary(cmp.text("REPORT SUMMARY"));

    JasperPdfExporterBuilder pdfExporter = Exporters.pdfExporter("report.pdf");
    rpt.toPdf(pdfExporter);
    File file = new File("report.pdf");

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");

    return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }
```

But this is not working. It generates blank report. If I use `rpt.addTitle(multiPageList);` instead of `rpt.addDetail(multiPageList);` report generates but page header doesn't appear on each page.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution that page header and page footer can be used only with the detail band. For using a detail band you need an data source attached to report. So set an empty data source to report and get the detail band where you can put data and also get use of page header and footer. A empty data source can be set as `rpt.setDataSource(new JREmptyDataSource());`Then report gets going with `rpt.addDetail(multiPageList);`. Thanks all.